# How to put Firebase RealtimeDatabase and FCM together

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I might have some versions' issue I guess? I was using

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'`

Everything works fine, now I want to add `RealtimeDatabase`

The **Assistant of Android Studio** suggested :

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
```

Official Guide suggest

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
```

Both resulting : Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin ... or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 15.0.2.

I know I might have to align their version, but I got

> Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:16.0.1.

or

> Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.2.

```
// If I use All official latest
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
```

> Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0.

So how can I put them together?

Official site : 
  `Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have added the Google maven respository to your root build.gradle`

But I did. (Did I?) Here is my `app.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.10.1'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

ext {
    roomVersion = '1.0.0'
    archLifecycleVersion = '1.1.0'
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
```

into this:

```
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

And use the following dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
```

More info here: [Firebase Release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)